# Logstash Docker Image - Missing logstash-plugin?

Tags: docker, logstash

We are using Elastic's Logstash Docker image (`docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:6.1.2`) as the base for our own Logstash Docker image build where we need to include a couple of logstash plugins for our own needs. However, when we look inside the base image under `/opt/logstash/bin` we can see that there is a `logstash-plugin.bat` file but there is no `logstash-plugin.sh` file. Is this file missing or are we looking at the wrong command for installing images?

This is our Dockerfile which at the moment fails to include the given plugins into the new image when built:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:6.1.2

ENV LOGSTASH_HOME /opt/logstash
WORKDIR ${LOGSTASH_HOME}

RUN rm -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf \
  bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-kafka \
  bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-prune

ADD pipeline/ /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
ADD config/ /usr/share/logstash/config/
```

How should we install logstash plugins based on v6.1.2 of Elastic's Logstash Docker image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was in the Dockerfile itself which was missing `&&` in between RUN commands which was therefore removing the logstash-plugin from the folder instead of executing it to install a plugin.

Correct Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:6.1.2

ENV LOGSTASH_HOME /opt/logstash
WORKDIR ${LOGSTASH_HOME}

RUN rm -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf && \
  bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-kafka && \
  bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-prune

ADD pipeline/ /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
ADD config/ /usr/share/logstash/config/
```